# c# crm dynamics. how to dynamically pass datatype field of T on GetAttributeValue<T>(fieldname)

Tags: c#, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

What is the good practice on passing values(datatype and fieldname) on `entity.GetAttributeValue<T>(fieldname)`. Currently I see something like : `entity.GetAttributeValue<string>(address)`. Is there any better way of doing this without specifically pass those prameters(string,address) on `.GetAttributeValue` method?

Currently I have a code like this:

```
var prop = typeof(PersonAddress).GetProperties(); 
string address;
foreach(var p in prop)
{
  address = entity.GetAttributeValue<p.PropertyType>(p.name)
}
```

but the `p.PropertyType` is not accepted as a reference type in `GetAttributeValue<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke [GetAttributeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx) generic method by using reflection and then construct it by supplying the type:

```
var getAttributeValueMethod = typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity).GetMethod("GetAttributeValue");
foreach (var property in typeof (PersonAddress).GetProperties())
{
    var generic = getAttributeValueMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
    var attributeValue = generic.Invoke(entity,
                                        new object[] {
                                        property.Name.ToLowerInvariant()});
}
```

Credits: [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method#answer-232621)